# Bash Terminal - .profile does not call some functions in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've had a hard time getting some of my functions in my `.profile` to work.

I often end up opening the file in my terminal copying the command and then pasting it in the terminal. So, the commands work.

But only about half of the functions work when I type directly in the terminal. The other half give me an error like: `-bash:   npm: command not found` or `-bash: Load: command not found`

Specifically two that really bug me are `set_registry_alt` and `reload`. I'm unable to access those but I'm able to access `set_registry_npm`. Is there something I'm missing that is causing inconsistencies in my `.profile`? Is there a way to make sure I don't some how have hidden characters causing problems?

Here's my code:

```
    variables=(
  "HTTP_PROXY"
  "HTTPS_PROXY"
  "ALL_PROXY"
  "all_proxy"
  "https_proxy"
)

function reload () {
  source ~/.profile
}

function set_registry_npm {
  npm config set registry="https://registry.npmjs.org/"
}

function set_registry_alt {
  npm config set registry="link_that_works_but_removed_for_StackOverflow"
}

function load_proxy_full {
  echo -n "Enter Username: "
  read username
  echo -n "Enter your Password: "
  read -s password
  url=http://${username}:${password}@proxy-change.xxxx.com:8080

  npm config set https-proxy ${url}
  npm config set proxy ${url}

  export HTTP_PROXY=${url}
  export HTTPS_PROXY=${url}
  export ALL_PROXY=${url}
  export all_proxy=${url}
  export https_proxy=${url}

  npm config delete registry
}

function unload_proxy {
  unset ${variables[@]}
  npm config delete https-proxy
  npm config delete proxy
}

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 

  function parse_git_branch {
    git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
  } 

  # This allows git autocomplete
    if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
       . ~/.git-completion.bash
    fi 

    # Node Path from Homebrew I believe
    export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"

    export VISUAL="subl -w"
    export SVN_EDITOR="subl -w"
    export GIT_EDITOR="subl -w"
    export EDITOR="subl -w"

function desktop {
  cd /Users/$USER/Desktop/$@
}

# Aliases
  alias l='ls -lah'

  # Git
  alias gcl="git clone"
  alias gst="git status"
  alias gpl="git pull"
  alias gp="git push"
  alias gd="git diff | mate"
  alias ga="git add"
  alias gcm="git commit -m"
  alias gb="git branch"
  alias gba="git branch -a"
  alias gcam="git commit -am"
  alias gbb="git branch -b"
  alias glol="git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph"


# Case-Insensitive Auto Completion
  bind "set completion-ignore-case on" 


  # via homebrew
  if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
  fi

export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"

[[ -s "/Users/$USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/$USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Comment: This line `Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` is supposed to be a comment.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, it was originally a comment. I just removed it but there's still something not quite right with this file.

Comment: `npm: command not found` means that either you haven't installed Node.js, or the directory where you installed it isn't in your `$PATH`.

Comment: @Barmar npm is installed. If I copy the inside of the function and paste that into my terminal then it works. Also `set_registry_npm` works.

Comment: Don't put `bash`-specific code in `.profile`, which may be sourced by shells other than `.bash`.

Comment: @chepner I had this code in my .bashrc file a while back and was having the same problems so a coworker recommended moving to my .profile. It obviously didn't fix it. What's your recommendation on what should be in a .profile vs a .bashrc vs a .bash_profile? I've always been confused on the differences.

Comment: `.profile` is used by *any* POSIX-compatible shell. (It's a bit of an academic point, I admit.) If `.bash_profile` exists, `bash` uses it instead of `.profile`. Both files are only used by login shells; `.bashrc` is used instead by non-login shells.

Comment: @chepner People don't generally change their login shell, so it's not a big deal to put shell-specific code in `.profile`.

Comment: Check the file for invisible characters before `npm` in the non-working function. Notice the extra space between `bash:` and `npm` in the error message.

Comment: @Barmar that was it! There was an invisible character before npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was two parts:

1. @barmar pointed out that this error message has a space before npm `-bash:   npm: command not found` and there was an invisible space that needed to be removed.
2. `Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` was supposed to be a comment so it was missing `#`.

These two things fixed my .profile

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

You should remove it.

Comment: Good catch. That fixed `reload` but not `npm_registry_alt`

Comment: I don't see `npm_registry_alt`. Do you mean `set_registry_alt`?